# How to make the domain validation with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The HTML:

```
 <input type="text" value="" id='u' name="url" /> //domain input text box
 <input name="" type="button" class="searchorange fl" onclick="get()" />
```

I am using Ajax to submit the "url" input text. My Code is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function get(){
     var u = $("#u").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"get",
            url:"/url/api/?u="+u,
            dataType:"json",
            data:"",
            success:function result(data){
                $("#show").html(data);
                $("#show").show();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

What I want is to add a validation using jQuery based on the user input. What should I  do?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

that's nothing about jquery, you can use Regexp to match the value of the `<input>`

```
if (/yourdomain\.com/.test($("#u").val())) {
    //DO AJAX
} else {
    //DO SOMETHING ELSE
}
```

**Update:**

Maybe you are looking for http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/url